# Saving nested objects with spring data - using an id as a reference

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Say you are creating a new entity of the type `User`, User has the nested object `Billing` given that you know that a `Billing` exists with the ID 1, is there a simple way with which you can form an association between a new `User` and an existing `Billing`?

Assume that fetching a `Billing` object to set to the user is an expensive operation, therefore the solution of fetching the entire Billing object and setting it to the user is not an option.

**My question is**, Is there a short hand method of saving this relationship between an entity and its nested counterpart, using spring data?

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int userId;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "billing_id")
    private Billing userBill;

    // constructor
    // getters and setters

}
```

For example in sudo code:

```
User bob = new User();
bob.billingId.id = 1;

userRepository.save(bob);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense if a `Billing` contained a `User`? What if there are multiple `Billings`?

Comment: The class was just an example really, i'm more trying to demonstrate in any situation that I have an entity that i need to create a relationship with an existing one can where i know the id of the existing entity, how can i add that relationship without having to fetch the entire record. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Absolutely.

`JpaRepository.getOne(id)` (as opposed to `CrudRepository.findById`) will call `EntityManager.getReference(entityType, id)` internally, which is the method designated to handle this exact use case (getting the reference to an entity, without loading its associated state).

To answer your question, what you want is: `customer.setBilling(billingRepository.getOne(billingId))`.

Comment: Wonderful thank you that's awesome,  looks like i've got a bit of tidy up to do

Comment: you don't need to check if it's null?

Comment: @roberttrudel Nope. Addording to the javadoc of `EntityManager.getReference()`: 'If the requested instance does not exist in the database, the EntityNotFoundException is thrown when the instance state is first accessed. (The persistence provider runtime is permitted to throw the EntityNotFoundException when getReference is called.)'. TL;DR the result of `getOne()` will never be `null`